# Manipulação de lista de listas com dicionário dentro de um laço em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista de listas, em que a listas internas contém palavras e cada lista interna representa as palavras de cada arquivo diferente.

`lista = [['carro','barco'],['moto','aviao'],['bike','skate']]`

ou seja a posição `lista[0]` representa o conjunto de palavras do arquivo `a.txt`

Possuo ainda uma estrutura de dicionário que contém palavras, a key do dicionário está servindo para enumerar cada palavra. Desta forma:

```
dic = {0:'bike',1:'carro',2:'caminhao',3:'navio',4:'jato',5:'moto'}
```

A minha intenção é salvar em outra `listaNova = [[]]`, e cada conjunto de palavras da `lista[i]` tiver uma palavra que seja igual a algum Value da chave do dicionario eu guardo a chave do dicionário nesta nova lista, mantendo a idéia de que cada posição da `listaNova[i]` esteja representando um arquivo. 
A meu problema é como fazer esse laço para comparar os valores.. já tentei varios jeitos porém nenhum funcionou.... estou fazendo algo como:

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
  for item in lista[i]:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if value == item:
            listaNova[i].append(key)
```

seria mais ou menos esse o caminho??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu algoritmo funcionaria. O problema aí seria só criar sua "listaNova" previamente, com uma lista para cada posição na lista original (e acertar o `==` no if).

Só que você tem um outro problema: está cirando uma porção de estruturas de dados interligadas entre si por chaves difíceis de visualizar. Quanod na verdade você quer é usar seus dados de forma eficiente.

Ok, legal, a sua listaNova vai conter chaves para o dicionário de palavras, vai ser mais compacta, talvez permita comparar onde palavras iguais ocorrem - mas o que realmente você quer fazer no final? Essa listaNova não seria tão eficiente, e seria ainda mais confusa de usar que sua lista original.

Não é melhor colocar tudo num banco SQL? Ou no MongoDB?

Ok, enquanto você não repensa seu problema, tem como resolver, criando a "listaNova" com:

listaNova = [list() for i in range(len(lista))]

e o seu código acima. Mas isso pode demorar - por que para cada palavra ele vai fazer uma busca linear no seu dicionário. O ideal é inverter o dicionário antes, daí de cada palavra você acha o índice direto. Com isso, da pra resolver com uma comprehension:

```
inverted_dic = {value:key for key, value in dic.items()}
lista_nova =  [[inverted_dic.get(palavra, -1) for palavra in item] for item in lista]
```

(O .get evita uma exceção se a palavra não existir no seu dicionário)

Comment: deu certo aqui! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! e porque vc passou esse -1 dentro desse metodo .get()?

Comment: O segundo parâmetro, opcional, para o get é o valor que será retornado se a chave não existir no dicionário. Assim, se alguma palavra não existir, ela vai aparecer com o índice "-1" na nova lista.

Comment: ahh entendi! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: se precisar muito, a biblioteca externa "extradict" tem um dicionário que mantém a relação reversa valor X chave automaticamente.